# Как залить реляционные данные в seeds.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Есть две таблицы - `Rubric` и `Question`. Связь многие ко многим. Стоит задача загрузить данные в базу через `seeds.rb`. Данные хранятся в xls. В принципе, понятно, как загрузить рубрики - берем все данные из ячеек рубрики, сплитим их по запятой, объединяем и заливаем в базу. Непонятно, как сделать привязку Вопросов к этим созданным рубрикам. Или как-то запрос сделать к базе? Подскажите правильный вариант.

```
|  № вопроса |   Заголовок |    Вопрос    |  Рубрика     |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|:------------:|
| 1          |  Заголовок1 |    Вопрос1   | наука, политика     
| 2          |  Заголовок2 |    Вопрос2   | журналистика   
| 3          |  Заголовок3 |    Вопрос3   | погода     
| 4          |  Заголовок4 |    Вопрос4   | наука      
| 5          |  Заголовок5 |    Вопрос5   | зима, лето, осень
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В таблице у вас хранятся названия рубрик через запятую. Массив названий рубрик для каждого вопроса. В модели `Question` вы можете объявить для этих названий виртуальный атрибут (нужен только сеттер). И в нем по принятому массиву - связывать запись `Question` с записями `Rubric`, находя или создавая их по названиям.

Вот пример сеттера в модели `Question`:

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :rubrics, through: :rubrics_questions
  has_many :rubrics_questions

  def rubric_names=(value)
    return if value.blank?
    self.rubrics = value.split(', ').map { |name| Rubric.where(name: name).first_or_initialize }
  end
end
```

А в `seeds.rb` вопросы создаются примерно так:

```
Question.where(id: id).first_or_create(title: title, text: text, rubric_names: rubric_names)
```